# Word to HTML conversion not working - PHP + ZEND

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, ms-word

Am new to PHP and this is my first time using Zend Framework to convert a Word file to HTML file. I am using this code.

```
<?php   
$mailMerge = new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge();
$mailMerge->setUsername('myUsername')->setPassword('myPassword');
$mailMerge->setLocalTemplate('docs/file.docx');
$mailMerge->assign(null);
$mailMerge->createDocument();
$data = $mailMerge->retrieveDocument('html');
file_put_contents('docs/file.html',$data);
?>
```

Copied from http://www.phplivedocx.org/2009/08/13/convert-docx-doc-rtf-to-html-in-php/

I've even included the path of Zend in `php.ini` file.

```
include_path = ".;c:\php\includes;C:\ZendFramework-1.12.11\library"
```

But its still showing me the error.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Service_LiveDocx_MailMerge' not found in C:\wamp\www\word2html_zend\index.php on line 2
```

I've googled it and also searched in stackoverflow search.. But no solution worked for me.. What should I do to get the code to work?

EDIT::

Am using Windows 8 operating system and PHP version 5.5.12

Comment: is this zf1? please remove the tag zend-framework2

Comment: try lower case c:\Zend\library also probably not it windows so the all file sys is case insensetive but i would try it any way, you must restart or reload the web server in case you didnt

Comment: Hi @talsibony... i've changed it to lower case and also restarted the web server... even though it's not working..

Comment: @phpfresher put phpinfo(); die(); in the top of the file and then make sure you are editing the correct php.ini look for the field Configuration File (php.ini) Path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not enough included the path for Zend. You need to register Zend autoloader before calling any class from Zend library,
like

```
// Initialize application loader
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Zend_');
```

Comment: Hii @Artak Dashyan.. i included the path..
`require_once("C:\ZendFramework-1.12.11\library\Zend\Loader\Autoloader.php");`

`Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->registerNamespace('Zend_');`


 and now its showing me this error..
`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Service_LiveDocx_Exception' with message 'Cannot read local template from disk.' in C:\ZendFramework-1.12.11\library\Zend\Service\LiveDocx\MailMerge.php on line 90`

Comment: check if "docs/file.docx" file is readable or have a proper access for you application.

Comment: because this exception generated from this `if (!is_readable($filename)) {
            throw new Zend_Service_LiveDocx_Exception(
                'Cannot read local template from disk.'
            );
        }`

Comment: Hii @Arshak Dashyan... thank you very much for your answer.. now it's working fine.. thank you very much...